Check against groups of constants
In my .NET Framework app (stuck at C# 7.3),
I use many if checks against group of constants in so many places (maintained more than 10 years).
Existing:
public static class Constants
{
    public const int Source1 = 111;
    public const int Source2 = 123;
    public const int Source3 = 135;
    // many more
    public const int Source999 = 1234;
}

// in some place
if(source == Constants.Source1 // belongs to group A
|| source == Constants.Source2 // belongs to group A
|| source == Constants.Source3 // belongs to group A
|| source == Constants.Source4 // belongs to group A & B
|| source == Constants.Source5 // belongs to group A & B
|| source == Constants.Source6) // belongs to group A & B
{ /** do something **/ }

// in other place
if(source == Constants.Source9 // belongs to group C
|| source == Constants.Source10 // belongs to group C
|| source == Constants.Source11) // belongs to group C
{ /** do something **/ }

// combination of groups B, C & D
if(source == Constants.Source4 // belongs to group A & B
|| source == Constants.Source5 // belongs to group A & B
|| source == Constants.Source6 // belongs to group A & B
|| source == Constants.Source7 // belongs to group B
|| source == Constants.Source8 // belongs to group B
|| source == Constants.Source9 // belongs to group C
|| source == Constants.Source10 // belongs to group C
|| source == Constants.Source11 // belongs to group C
|| source == Constants.Source12 // belongs to group D 
|| source == Constants.Source13 // belongs to group D
|| source == Constants.Source14 // belongs to group D & E
|| source == Constants.Source15) // belongs to group D & E
{ /** do something **/ }

// groups B, C & D with exception of A & E
if(source == Constants.Source7 // belongs to group B
|| source == Constants.Source8 // belongs to group B
|| source == Constants.Source9 // belongs to group C
|| source == Constants.Source10 // belongs to group C
|| source == Constants.Source11 // belongs to group C
|| source == Constants.Source12 // belongs to group D 
|| source == Constants.Source13) // belongs to group D
{ /** do something **/ }

The problem:
Readability and maintainability.
I always change many conditions when introducing new source.
After years, the need of grouping them becoming clear.
The change:
Instead of checking against group of constants, it should check against group of groups of constants.
So I start defining the groups:
public static class SourceGroups
{
    public static int[] A => new[] {
            Constants.Source1,
            Constants.Source2,
            Constants.Source3,
            Constants.Source4,
            Constants.Source5,
            Constants.Source6
    };

    public static int[] B => new[] {
            Constants.Source4,
            Constants.Source5,
            Constants.Source6,
            Constants.Source7,
            Constants.Source8
    };

    // many more
}

// most usages becomes very simple
if (SourceGroups.A.Contains(source))
{ /** do something **/ }
    
// as well as combination of groups
if (SourceGroups.B.Contains(source)
 || SourceGroups.C.Contains(source)
 || SourceGroups.D.Contains(source))
{ /** do something **/ }

// combination with exception
foreach(var item in items)
{
  var source = item.Source;

  // it sacrifice performance here due to preparing the correct list before checking
  var eligibleForOperation1 = SourceGroups.B
                      .Concat(SourceGroups.C)
                      .Concat(SourceGroups.D)
                      .Except(SourceGroups.A)
                      .Except(SourceGroups.E);

  if (eligibleForOperation1.Contains(item.Source))
  {
    // operation 1
  }

  // and sacrifice performance here
  var eligibleForOperation2 = SourceGroups.F
                      .Concat(SourceGroups.G)
                      .Except(SourceGroups.H);

  if (eligibleForOperation2.Contains(item.Source))
  {
    // operation 2
  }
}

Performance sacrifice in the last case. But, I guess, It's still okay-ish.
I might miss something so I appreciate if you guys have any feedback.

Can you use hierarchy for grouping? Or is there any constant which is part of multiple groups?

BTW here at CodeReview we prefer real code fragments not made up examples (even if it is made for the shake of simplicity).

What is special about those values? Are there really ~1000 of them? Are the values of any two tokens the same value? Is the highest value really 1234? More background information, please. (var source = item.Source; ... The variable source doesn't appear to be used anywhere.)

The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions for guidance on writing good question titles.

#include <ctype.h> provides access to a number of very fast "look-up" functions to check the characteristics of up to 256 different binary values (typically ASCII characters). For example only one of isupper() and islower() would be true if isalpha() is true. A simple table looked of one element whose address is one byte but whose content is (likely) 16 bits wide for 16 different properties. Can you see a solution to your problem that is analogous to this that doesn't invoke so much code?

I suggest a different model where you declare each constant only once and specify the groups it belongs to. For this we declare the following struct:
public readonly struct Source
{
    public readonly int Value;
    public readonly bool A;
    public readonly bool B;
    public readonly bool C;
    public readonly bool D;
    public readonly bool E;

    public Source(int value, bool a = false, bool b = false, bool c = false, bool d = false, bool e = false)
    {
        Value = value;
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
        D = d;
        E = e;
    }
}

The constructor parameters a to e are optional and default to false. We can then easily declare the sources by specifying only the groups they belong to by using named parameters:
public static class Constants
{
    public static readonly Source Source1 = new Source(111, a: true);
    public static readonly Source Source2 = new Source(123, a: true);
    public static readonly Source Source3 = new Source(135, a: true);
    public static readonly Source Source4 = new Source(147, a: true, b: true);
    public static readonly Source Source5 = new Source(159, a: true, b: true);
    // ...

    public static readonly Dictionary<int, Source> Sources = new Dictionary<int, Source> {
        [Source1.Value] = Source1,
        [Source2.Value] = Source2,
        [Source3.Value] = Source3,
        [Source4.Value] = Source4,
        [Source5.Value] = Source5,
        // ...
    };
}

You would get a constant with int c = Constants.Source5.Value;.
And then do checks like this by querying the dictionary once (note that a dictionary lookup O(1) is faster than searching an array O(n)):
int sourceNumber = 135;
var source = Constants.Sources[sourceNumber];
if (source.B || source.C || source.D) {
    // Do something
}

If you are not sure whether a number is a valid source, you can test
if (Constants.Sources.TryGetValue(sourceNumber, out Source source) &&
    (source.B || source.C || source.D)) {

    // Do something
}

